# Pydantic from_orm() method

Tags: python, pydantic

I have one Pydantic model

```
class Clas1(pydantic_utils.DefaultBaseModel):
    created: bool
    updated: bool
    third_field: bool
```

and an orm model

```
class Orm1():
    created: bool
    updated: bool
```

the orm model doesnt have the 'third_field'
how can i still use 'from_orm' without getting validation errors? (and no optional for this field)

thanks

Comment: could you just give it a default value? e.g. `third_field: bool = False`

Comment: I rather not do that, I want it to be required for any other purposes but still use the orm->pydantic assignment in one particular place

Comment: You could add the `third_field = False` attr to `Orm1` instead...

Comment: Otherwise, give up on "orm mode" and use `parse_obj` instead. You'll need your own way of getting an `Orm1` instance as a dict, but then you can merge `{"third_field": False}` when making the `parse_obj` call

Comment: so im guessing there is no way to do it with pydantic? 
thank you!